# What is the difference between extension and plugin in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Yes, I'm beginner. and I used Webstorm but now using Vscode.
I know to say 'extension' in Vscode.
But sometimes to say 'plugin' in Vscode.(ex. Do you know Vscode's Prettier plugin?)

**Can others understand this?**

I understand it like this Python's pip and Node's npm to understand.
Just different name.
Is that what I understand right?

Answer (score 0):

There is very thin border line between the two.
Extension and plugins often confused people. And Mostly people believe both are same.

1. The main difference between the two is that plug-in provides extra functionality which does not modify the core functionality.
   While extension is made for modifying core functionality, may be provided due to version change or improvement.
2. Securing plugins is more complex than extension.
3. Extension are individual identity so one extension needs one set of privileges, whereas plugins are more complicated and needs to identify privileges for each application runs plugins rather than a whole plugin.
4. Extension is specific to particular application. It extends functionality of a particular application or software.
   While plug-in can be made generalized which may runs independently in coordination with particular application or software.